# Enduro MTB or Downhill for 14 year old?

Tags: mountain-bike

I'm not sure which one to get. I'm 14 and will hopefully be getting into downhill but I'm not sure if I want to go all the way. This is my first full suspension bike.

Comment: What type of bike are you upgrading from? "Hoping" you can get into DH, sounds a lot like you have to consider the logistics. For instance, I'm guessing you can't drive yet, do you have enough trails near you or even a park? What makes you want to Downhill? Do you want to spend more money on accessories? There are a lot of factors, outside of getting on your bike, if you know what I mean.... You need to give the details. It's not simple.

Answer (score 8):

Enduro or AM (All-Mountain) mate. They are more versatile, especially if you don't know if you are going to stick with DH.

These days, DH bikes only do one thing. If you don't know what that is or haven't been hooked yet, move the cash to an AM. A half decent AM bike will be a handful already for any novice.

Plus you can pedal back up and you will enjoy that more than waiting for adults to drive you back up.

Answer (score 2):

Others will give their opinions on DH vs Endurance.  Which do you prefer to ride?

Other things to consider:  Given you're 14, you are still growing.   Any bike you get now has to allow for lengthening legs and arms and body mass.

Do you use the bike for anything else?  Riding to school or afterschool job?
If you can afford it, bikes with suspension lockouts will be more useable than bikes that bounce about on the pavement.

And your budget comes into the choice as well.  Personally I would look for an older bike that is a good size for now, get more experience and look for a replacement when you're about 18, where your limbs have reached their approximate full size, and then step up.  At that point you'll have more experience too.

Don't be fooled by shiny bling, fruit, or go-fast accessories.  Do make sure your safety gear is up to the job - that's more important than the bike.

Comment: Bonus points if the older bike is pre-scratched.  You won't have the emotional baggage of putting a scratch on a shiny new bike.  Since used bikes don't seem to have much perceived value, then you can push it harder to add your own scratch.